# multiple column in sqllite using regular expression

Tags: regex, sqlite

there is a table in sqlite with multiple similar column names, like xyz_1,xyz_2,xyz_3....... apart from other regular columns, like cde,efg,ghi,abc.

Is there a way i can do a select on only these columns in a table, without specifying the full column list?
Can i use  a regular expression in selecting column names in select statement?

`Select abc* from table;`

Comment: No there isn't. You should probably rethink your design, and move those columns into a separate table where they're separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

As a trick you can achieve it.

Below is the PHP example but logic will work for you. Here you can select all fields from the database and make another request to fetch the filtered column.

```
$string_to_check = 'sample';
$valid = false;
$q = mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM tbl_name");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {
  if($row->Field == $string_to_check) {
     $valid = true; break;
  }
}
if($valid) {
  echo "Field exists";
}
```

OR

you can run this `SHOW FIELDS FROM tbl_name` in a single query and on the basis of replies, you can make filter the column names and make another select statement based on it.

Comment: Hi Rohit.. My database is in sqlite.. SHOW is not available in sqlite.

Comment: see if this helps `PRAGMA table_info(table_name);`